# Changing URL on radio button selection

Tags: javascript, jquery, forms, radio-button

I'm trying to change the URL when I select radio button.

I have found [an answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32840406/update-or-replace-url-parameters-using-jquery-based-on-select-option) that works for 'select' form elements, but if I apply it to my radio buttons it lists out all the options instead of the one that is selected

My JS

```
$('.unitfiltercontrol').change(function(){
    var params =[];
    $('.unitfiltercontrol').each(function(){
        $this=$(this);
        if(!$this.val()=='') params.push($this.data('param')+'='+encodeURIComponent( $this.val() ));
    });
    $('#urlDisplay').text(window.location.href+('?'+params.join('&'))); //print to div for testing
});
```

My HTML:

```
<form>
  <input id="radio1" type="radio" value="1" name="foo" data-param="foo" class="unitfiltercontrol">
  <input id="radio2" type="radio" value="2" name="foo" data-param="foo" class="unitfiltercontrol">

  <input id="radio3" type="radio" value="1" name="bar" data-param="bar" class="unitfiltercontrol">
  <input id="radio4" type="radio" value="2" name="bar" data-param="bar" class="unitfiltercontrol">
</form>
<div id="urlDisplay"></div>
```

So if I select `radio1`, instead of the URL being displayed as:

> /?foo=1

I get:

> /?foo=1&foo=2&bar=1&bar=2

How would I modify this to work with radio buttons?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Radio button in your case make single selection , so no need to loop each radio , just get in the change the value and data for current clicked , then create object using data-param as key , after that loop thorough keys and create and array of key + values as below ; snippet :

```js
let values = {};

$('.unitfiltercontrol').change(function(e){
  let data = $(this).data('param');
  let value = this.value;
  values[data] = value;
  let params = [];
  
  let keys = Object.keys(values);
  
  for(inc = 0; inc < keys.length ; inc ++) {
    let key = keys[inc];
    params.push(key+'='+encodeURIComponent(values[key]))
  }
  
    $('#urlDisplay').text(window.location.href+('?'+params.join('&'))); 
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
My HTML:

<form>
  <input id="radio1" type="radio" value="1" name="foo" data-param="foo" class="unitfiltercontrol">
  <input id="radio2" type="radio" value="2" name="foo" data-param="foo" class="unitfiltercontrol">

  <input id="radio3" type="radio" value="1" name="bar" data-param="bar" class="unitfiltercontrol">
  <input id="radio4" type="radio" value="2" name="bar" data-param="bar" class="unitfiltercontrol">
</form>

<div id="urlDisplay"></div>
<div id="urlDisplay">

</div>
```

Comment: I see, thank you, that works for 1 radio button. What if I have multiple radio buttons that I want added to to the URL e.g. /?foo=1&bar=1. Currently the code displays just the last parameter regardless of the radio button used. I have updated the question HTML.

Comment: @user2265915 okey now I understand , could you see edited answer

Answer (score 1):

Hi friend you can use if condition when pushing parameters to like below

```
$('.unitfiltercontrol').change(function(){
var params =[];
$('.unitfiltercontrol').each(function(){
    $this=$(this);
    if ($(this).prop("checked")) { //get the values of only checked radio buttons
       if(!$this.val()=='') params.push($this.data('param')+'='+encodeURIComponent( $this.val() ));
    }
    
});
$('#urlDisplay').text(window.location.href+('?'+params.join('&'))); //print to div for testing
```

});